# correct spelling of jus domicilii, jus soli, and jus nexi

Tags: legal-latin

I understand that that the correct spelling of the legal term for law of residence is: "jus domiciliī" (with a line over the i), and "just solī" (with the line) for law of soil. Would it also be jus nexī (with the line) for law of connection?

Answer (score 6):

In terms of correct Latin grammar the answer is no, because *nexus* is a different type of noun than *domicilium* and *solum*. The latter are second-declension nouns, so their genitive ("of") form ends in -ī; but *nexus* is a fourth-declension noun, so its genitive ends in -ūs. "Law of connection" would thus be *jūs nexūs*. (Note that if you are using macrons, which are optional and usually left out, then the *u* of *jūs* has one too. Also, an alternative and equally correct spelling of *jūs* is *iūs*.)

However, googling *jus nexi* shows that it appears to be an existing, though recently coined, legal term. It is incorrect Latin, though. If you're asking whether the macron would be used on the incorrect *i* of *nexi*, then the answer is yes, if you're writing with macrons, but these are usually omitted except in textbooks and beginner's texts.

Comment: WHOOPS. Have deleted my incorrect answer, which wouldn't have been incorrect if I'd given it two seconds' thought.